# sending data to php from js via ajax post - error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass data from my js file to a php file by using ajax (as you can see below).

I've checked the php error log and saw that the data I sent via POST isn't recognized by php (getting "trying to get property of non-object" error).

I've also posted my php code below if fails on the last line, when I refer to $json->func.

Am I doing it right? I've seen some examples of using jquery's post function, but I like the ajax way with the success and error, so I've been trying to stick to it.

Appreciate the help :)

js:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType : "json",
            data: {func:'getSummId' ,summName: summonerName},
            success: function(json){
                           //bla bla bla
           }
            error: function(){
                           //bla bla bla
           }
```

php:

```
    <?php
        header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        $client_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $json = json_decode($client_data);
        switch ($json->func) {
        ...
```

Comment: i think you want in your `php` is the `$_POST`?

Comment: Try `$json->{'func'}` instead.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({func:'getSummId' ,summName: summonerName}),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataType` refers to the data being returned, not how you are sending the data.
So your data is going to be in the `$_POST` global variable, and using php://input will not work in this case with json_decode

So you can either use

```
$func = $_POST['func'];
$summName = $_POST['summName'];
```

Or you can try setting the content type option in your jQuery ajax request (though i have never tried this so you will have to test it)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType : "json",
    data: {func:'getSummId' ,summName: summonerName},
```

When `contentType` is not set it defaults to

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

PHP automatically parses that type of request into the $_GET/$_POST/$_REQUEST globals. PHP does not natively know how automatically parse application/json requests sent to it. So when wanting to send request data as json you have to read `php://input` yourself.

Comment: That's working. Thanks! 
Though, what's the difference between that and php://input ?

I've used php://input before when using $http in angular...

Comment: See updated answer, as for it working with angular, it may auto set the content type header by detecting the type of data object you pass $http

Answer (score 0):

Try to change: `type: "POST"` to `method: "POST"`

Comment: `type` is an alias for `method`